# Specify a cascading delete for parent / child relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

Model:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Guid? ParentMenuItemId {get;set;}
    public virtual MenuItem ParentMenuItem {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItems {get;set;}
}
```

current mapping:

```
HasOptional(m => m.ParentMenuItem).WithMany(p => p.ChildMenuItems).HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentMenuItemId);
```

I tried adding the `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)`, but I got an error. How should I update my mapping to allow for cascading deletes? So, If I delete a Parent, all the children will be deleted. Do I have to do this manually?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 2):

In your model, just look at the association's properties. There is an OnDelete that you can set to Cascade. The XML should look like this:

```
<OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
```