# Entity Framework "The relationship could not be changed" with simple one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying to remove a relationship with the following code:

```
                var serverVideo = InternalGetVideo(db, videoId);

                // get owning user
                var owner = InternalGetUser(db, serverVideo.UserId);

                // Add/remove video to user's upvotedVideos
                if (owner.UpvotedVideos.Contains(serverVideo))
                {
                    serverVideo.UpVotes--;
                    SaveChanges(db); // Works
                    owner.UpVotes--;
                    SaveChanges(db); // Works
                    owner.UpvotedVideos.Remove(serverVideo);
                    SaveChanges(db); // Breaks
                }

                SaveChanges(db);
```

But I always get this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I'm not trying to delete the video, I'm just trying to remove it from the user's UpvotedVideos property (it's there):

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int UpVotes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Video> UpvotedVideos { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Videos does not contain a reference to UserProfiles - it's a one-to-many relationship.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Videos class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }  // user that created the video, unrelated

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I think it might be helpful if you could post your `Video` class, at least the parts dealing with the relationship to `UserProfile` (the foreign key and the relationship property).

Comment: I'm assuming `db` is your context and is not disposed of throughout?

Comment: If you delete the server video before saving the changes, does it work?

Comment: @Steve - I can do db.Remove(serverVideo) instead and it works, but that's not what I'm trying to do - I'm just trying to remove the relationship.

Comment: Apparently, if you're using self-tracking entities with EF4, you *might* be seeing a bug that's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16003544/425871

Comment: @Steve so simply removing a relationship in a basic one-to-many setup doesn't work out of the box?  That's either tragic or I've given you the wrong information... isn't that what ORMs are for?

Comment: Are you positive that EF doesn't think that `UserId` in `Video` is a foreign key? That would cause this issue. Try renaming it to something else and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Well, yes - I've never experienced the problem you're having, though. The link I provided is apparently a bug and Microsoft apparently advises against using self-tracking entities. Did you try the solution at the link?

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider upgrading to EF5. I successfully did that a couple months ago... I reverse engineered my DB to a code-first model. The `DbContext` EF5 uses is *almost* compatible with `ObjectContext`, and the transition was relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment in source code:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }  // user that created the video, unrelated
```

**Unrelated?** Most likely this is the foreign key for the one-to-many relationship in question because mapping conventions will detect it as the foreign key since it has the same name as the primary key property `UserId` in `UserProfile`. And because the property has a non-nullable type `int` EF will detect the relationship as **required** which means that no video can exist without having a user who upvoted it.

This is what the exception says when you remove the video from the `UpvotedVideos` collection which means that the relationship to the current user who upvoted the video is removed. You *can* do this but because every video must have a user who upvoted it you must assign the video either to another user or delete the video altogether.

Well, apparently you don't want that a video *must* have a user who upvoted it but instead a video can be without any upvotes. In this case the relationship must be **optional**. You can achieve this in several ways:

- Break the conventional mapping by renaming the `UserId` property, for example

  ```
  public int CreatorId { get; set; }  // user that created the video, unrelated
  ```

  Now, this property is *really* unrelated and just a scalar property with no relationship at all. By default the relationship introduced by the `UpvotedVideos` collection is optional now because it doesn't have a required foreign key property on the other side.
- Override the mapping convention with Fluent API:

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
      .HasMany(u => u.UpvotedVidoes)
      .WithOptional()
      .Map(m => m.MapKey("UpvoterId")); // <- FK column name
  ```
- Introduce a second (nullable) property and define it as the foreign key with data annotations:

  ```
  [DataContract]
  public class Video
  {
      [Key]
      [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
      public int VideoId { get; set; }

      [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
      public int UserId { get; set; } // user that created the video, unrelated

      public int? UpvoterId { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataMember]
      public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  And in `UserProfile`:

  ```
  [ForeignKey("UpvoterId")]
  public virtual List<Video> UpvotedVideos { get; set; }
  ```

There are probably more variants that include adding navigation properties in `Video`, etc. But in all cases the relationship must be defined as optional to make your code working.

Side note: Shouldn't the relationship be many-to-many btw? A user can upvote many videos and a video can be upvoted by many users? But that's another question...

Comment: Thank you so much Slauma.  I'll give this a shot now.  To answer your last question - I want it to be a one-to-many because I never need to know which users have upvoted a given video - I just need to know what videos a given user has upvoted.  So i'm trying to keep the relationships as simple as possible.  Does that make sense or am I wrong?

Comment: @RobVious: You must use a many-to-many mapping with Fluent API then if you don't want a navigation property in `Video` refering to `User`s, like: `modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasMany(u => u.UpvotedVidoes).WithMany().Map(...);` The parameterless `WithMany()` says "no navigation property in `Video`" but it is still a many-to-many relationship. Defining it as one-to-many does not express your business logic correctly (that a video can be upvoted by *many* and not only by *one* user) and is wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
owner.UpvotedVideos.Remove(serverVideo);
```

Try:

```
var video = owner.UpvotedVideos.Where(x => x == serverVideo).FirstOrDefault();
db.Videos.Remove(video); // notice, I'm removing it straight from my DB context
//so make sure you have Videos as a part of your DbContext
db.Entry(video).State = EntityState.Deleted; // tell the ChangeTracker you've removed somethings
db.SaveChanges();
```

When you try to remove right from the `owner`, EF doesn't allow nulls within navigation properties. Also, when I tried making Foreign keys optional - I saw that they still remain in the DB. I didn't need all of those orphan records in there, so I used this solution.